# Whether there is ConcurrentModificationException or not in loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a snippet code below. I have 2 threads A and B running at the same time.

```
List<String> listPeople = new ArrayList<>();
// Add more item
.....

Thread A
for (String item : listPeople) {
    System.out.println("Name is: " + item.name);
}

Thread B
- add/remove item to list people
```

With this form of for loop, it loops via `iterator` of List. So Will it crash with the `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: As @Daniel Pryden explains in his answer you can't count on it. Sometimes it may throw ConcurrentModificationException and other times it may not.

Comment: Thanks for yr answer. For safety, I should use for(; ;) statement, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`ConcurrentModificationException` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a *different* thread. [...]
>
> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *`ConcurrentModificationException` should be used only to detect bugs.*

Comment: Thanks for yr answer. For safety, I should use for(; ;) statement, right?

Comment: @HuyDuongTu: No, for safety you should either avoid sharing the collection across threads or else use a thread-safe implementation. For example, you can synchronize all accesses of the `ArrayList` variable using the same monitor lock.